# Java ValueEventListener infinite loop

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble with my Firebase code to add a contact to a user profile.   This exact code used to work fine, and now as of today it gets itself into an infinite loop and creates contacts repeatedly until I force kill the application.  I can't work out where the loop is, or what may have changed!

Code:

```
public class AddContacts extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText addContactNumber;
private Button btnAddContact;
private String userResult, searchPhone, ping_userID;
private FirebaseAuth pingAuth;
DatabaseReference ref;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener pingAuthListener;

    addContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addContactNumber);
    btnAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddContact);



    btnAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            searchPhone = addContactNumber.getText().toString();
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
            ref.orderByChild("Phone").equalTo(searchPhone).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        userResult = datas.getKey();
                        if (userResult != null) {
                            ping_userID = pingAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference newContact = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles").child(ping_userID).child("Contacts");
                            newContact.setValue(userResult);
                            DatabaseReference newContactPing = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles").child(ping_userID).child("Contacts").child(userResult).child("PingStatus");
                            newContactPing.setValue(false);
                            DatabaseReference addRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles").child(userResult).child("Name");
                            addRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String resultName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                    DatabaseReference addContactName = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles").child(ping_userID).child("Contacts").child(userResult).child("Name");
                                    addContactName.setValue(resultName);
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User: " + resultName + " added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    ref.removeEventListener(this);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ref.removeEventListener(this);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Also, perhaps as an aside, it never triggers the "User not found" event, even if I enter details that are not in the database.

Any ideas?   I am sure it is staring me in the face but I don't see it.

@Peter Haddad Database as requested:

```
MyAppDatabase
  -Profiles
    -BCsuC4XAZqVhWj
      -Name: "Simon"
      -Phone:  123456
      -Contacts
        -pnYn1NhzzNQAm
          -Name: "Bill"
          -PingStatus: false

     -pnYn1NhzzNQAm
       -Name:  "Bill"
       -Phone:   987654
       -Contacts
          -BCsuC4XAZqVhWj
            -Name: "Simon"
            -PingStatus: false
```

Comment: show your database please

Comment: Database added as requested, thank you!

Comment: If I start from a blank contacts list, and Simon tries to add Bill, it keeps adding Bill over and over and over again until I force kill the app.   I have added the information here so it is clear what the end output should look like.

Comment: Can you try changing this: _ref.orderByChild("Phone").equalTo(searchPhone).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {_ to addListenerForSingleValueEvent? Because it looks like you are changing the data inside the eventlistener so effectively it is calling itself and thus creating the infinite loop.

Comment: That works, Andre!   Want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` in both the cases.